# Android Fragment crash when previews fragment not loaded

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

While fragment A stills loads a couple textViews and Images, i change to fragment B and app crashes. I thought it could be caused by the AsyncTasks which still run in background but i could not find anything related to this. Anyone got any idea how to solve this issue?

```
      FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
    at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:333)
    at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:319)
    at com.petcial.petopen.fragments.StatusFragment.setMyPets(StatusFragment.java:287)
    at com.petcial.petopen.fragments.StatusFragment$userPets.onPostExecute(StatusFragment.java:361)
    at com.petcial.petopen.fragments.StatusFragment$userPets.onPostExecute(StatusFragment.java:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:112)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

Update

The idea is that everything works fine if i wait for my fragments to load till the end, till all elements load. If i don't, and go to any other fragment, the app crashes.

```
// line 287
Picasso.with(context).load(GlobalData.myPetsImage[0]).into(myPetsImage);
```

I guess the library loads the image after i change the fragment, and throws " Target must not be null."

Comment: You need to post some code. All we can say now is that your Target is null..

Comment: updated my question. Please take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after finding out that the image in Fragment A loads after the fragment B loads, as it is downloaded from server, i put a try catch statement around image loader and it fixed my problem